# Create a Unique Conversation Number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a private message system and I want to assign a unique conversation number so I can Identify if multiple users are taking part to the same conversation. I was thinking to assign the Userid of the person who send the message + `microtime()`  like this:

```
$conversation_number =  md5($_POST['user_id']+microtime());
```

Would this code originate always a unique number or it may also possible that, accidentally, it generate the same number for the subsequent messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think php `uniqid` is sufficient

From PHP DOC

> If set to TRUE, uniqid() will add additional entropy (using the combined linear congruential generator) at the end of the return value, which increases the likelihood that the result will be unique

try

```
  uniqid('id', true)
```

However there are approximately 3.402823669209387e+38 different values in a 32 digit hex value (16^32) in `md5` the your odds are phenomenally small that there will be a duplicate all the same

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**uniqid**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), which is used to generate a unique ID.

Comment: you have been really quick to reply but I think Baba explanation is really good and all the answers are correct! How should I decide which one I have to accept? is there a guideline?;-)

Comment: @mattia I think there is no rule for this, just accept the answer you like :)

Comment: well you have almost 40.000... i'm sure you will not get offended..thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [UniqId()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function?